# Read-Only TextArea with Scrollbar [JavaFx]

Tags: java, javafx, textarea, fxml

I'm trying to make a TextArea readonly, but the text I am setting the TextArea to is so long it needs to be scrolled. A scroll bar appears when the text is set, but the scrollbar is not functioning.

I am using an .fxml file to hold my TextArea with the following code:

```
<TextArea fx:id="consultantScheduleTextArea" editable="false" focusTraversable="false" prefHeight="454.0" prefWidth="597.0" visible="false" />
```

My understanding is this is making it so I can't focus on it (like tab to the container or click into it), its not editable (so I can't change the text by typing), and it starts invisible. I've tried setting focusTraversable to true with no change of behavior.

In my controller, I set the visibility to true when a button is clicked then get some string data from a db, format it a certain way, then do this to set the content of the TextArea.

```
myTextArea.appendText(myString);
```

The result is my TextArea is filled with the content I have in myString, scrollbar is auto-created because the string is actually a lot of lines (lets say 300 lines), but again I cannot scroll it.

Any help?

**EDIT:** I didn't mention, this TextArea is wrapped in a stackpane which is wrapped in a gridpane. I don't think these matter at all, but just in case. This hierarchy is because its part of a complete app I have and  this is just one component on one of the GUIs.

Comment: I just recreated what you said you did and I have no problem. Make sure you are using the latest jdk.

Comment: I just tried it with a very long string. It took a while to load but once loaded the scroll bar worked.

Comment: Try this to make sure your gui is not locking. Just a wild guess. Platform.runLater(()->{consultantScheduleTextArea.appendText(text.toString());});  and use StringBuilder where you can.

Comment: I don't think the GUI is locking as I can click other elements right away and change the scene around.

I am using string builder up until text.toString() in the .appendText() call.

I'm on the latest JDK too, haha.

Comment: They were just wild guesses. I couldn't recreate your problem.

Comment: I appreciate the help. Going to load up the project on my laptop and see if its reproduced I guess.

Comment: So I copied out the textarea element and into a new area of my gui and it works fine. like I can scroll it and everything.

It's wrapped in a stackpane, any other thoughts on what may happen here that's causing the issue?

Answer (score 4):

try to use this on your TextArea

```
myTextArea.setEditable(false);
```

this make your text area read only and will make the scrollbar enable

Comment: I do that in the fxml...

editable= "false"

I did this in code as you said instead of fxml, still doesn't work, these function the same so I didn't think so. tried anyway :)

Comment: where did you add it exactly ? in which part of your code you add it ?

Comment: On the FXML, when you create an item the property can be set there. Or you can set it in the controller. I've done both to make it editable(false) and neither work.

Comment: ok please remove any edit you made. back it to default and use this code in your constructor and tell me the result

Answer (score 2):

Alright, so some how with it being inside a stack pane, the scroll was not working. Not sure why, but that happened.

Unwrapped from stack pane and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having a similar problem. My TextArea was in a Pane as a first element of the childrens and the scrollbar in the textarea was not working, I had to move it to the last element and it worked fine.